# No route matches [GET] "/oauth/applications"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

When I try to go to /oauth/applications

I got 404

I don't see the route when I do :

> rails routes | grep oauth

I want to have a 200 and to access the page.

My configuration :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use (needs plugins)
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    User.find_by(id: session[:current_user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end

  # In this flow, a token is requested in exchange for the resource owner credentials (username and password)
  resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
    user = User.where(login: params[:username]).first
    if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      user
    end
  end

  # Access token expiration time (default 2 hours).
  # If you want to disable expiration, set this to nil.
  access_token_expires_in 1.day

  # implicit and password grant flows have risks that you should understand
  # before enabling:
  #   http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.2
  #   http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.3
  #
  grant_flows %w(password authorization_code client_credentials)
  # grant_flows %w[password]

  # Under some circumstances you might want to have applications auto-approved,
  # so that the user skips the authorization step.
  # For example if dealing with a trusted application.
  # skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
  #   client.superapp? or resource_owner.admin?
  # end
  skip_authorization do
    true
  end

  admin_authenticator do |routes|
    User.find_by(id: session[:admin_id], roles: '{100}') || redirect_to(routes.new_user_session_url)
  end

  # default_scopes :read, :write
  # optional_scopes :create, :update

  # WWW-Authenticate Realm (default "Doorkeeper").
  # realm "Doorkeeper"
end
```

And in my router.rb file :

```
 use_doorkeeper do
    # No need to register client application
    skip_controllers :applications, :authorized_applications
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
  use_doorkeeper do
    # No need to register client application
    skip_controllers :applications, :authorized_applications
  end
```

I used :

```
  use_doorkeeper
```

I was skipping the applications controller

Comment: I don't skip mine but it doesn't appear. I'm using `api_only` mode of doorkeeper.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `use_doorkeeper` to your `routes.rb`? It must look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  use_doorkeeper
  # your routes
end
```

This will mount following routes:

```
GET       /oauth/authorize/native?code
GET       /oauth/authorize
POST      /oauth/authorize
DELETE    /oauth/authorize
POST      /oauth/token
POST      /oauth/revoke
POST      /oauth/introspect
resources /oauth/applications
GET       /oauth/authorized_applications
DELETE    /oauth/authorized_applications/:id
GET       /oauth/token/info
```

Additional details about routes configuration you can find here: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-routes

You can find more info in [official README](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/README.md) or in the [Wiki](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki) (here you can also find some external articles on how to install and configure Doorkeeper gem).

Answer (score 1):

Please add below line in your route.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  use_doorkeeper
  # your routes
end
```

Check from documentation https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#routes